# CodeIgniter / Gmail SMTP timeout on IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send a simple email with codeigniter:

```
    $email_config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $email_config);
    $this->email->from('no-reply@mysite.com', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to($email_address); 
    $this->email->subject('Test Subject');
    $this->email->message('Test Message');  
    $this->email->send();
```

But it just times out. I have uncommented extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini,
but I'm guessing there's some sort of other setup issue. I'm running on IIS7.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking your server's outgoing internet connection just to make sure everything is working ok? Also, I'd check the firewall settings too.

It just doesn't look like a CI or PHP issue to me, my configs to send out via gmail look just like that so you're all good there.